# Coldfusion Datefield controls do not scroll with the rest of the page in IE7

Tags: internet-explorer, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have created a form within a cfwindow that contains Coldfusion date controls *cfinput type="datefield"*

My issue is: when using the scroll bar, the form scrolls as expected, except for the date controls, which do not move relative to the window. This happens regardless of whether the Calendar Control is open.

Everything works fine in all browsers and versions except for IE7 and Quirks mode - which is a requirement for my customer.

Will be happy to provide added information on request if needed.